# upper bound for $e^{ax^2}$

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, exponentiation, exponential-function

I want to find a upper bound for $$e^{ax^2}\leqslant \: ?$$
"a" is a constant and $a\geqslant 0$ .
x is a variable.
I prefer to have a  polynomial function or power function (like $ x^{k}$)

is there any upper bound for it?

thanks a lot

Comment: For $a\gt 0$, in the long run your function grows much more rapidly than any polynomial.

Comment: Exponentials cannot be bounded by polynomials.

Comment: Since $e^x = \sum_k \frac{x^k}{k!}$, you can see that $e^x \geq \frac{x^k}{k!}$ for any $k \ge 0$.

Comment: @copper.hat what about $x < 0$?

Comment: $$e^{ax^2}\leqslant \: 3^{ax^2}$$ =D

Answer (score 2):

There is no polynomial upper bound for $e^{ax^2}$ when $a > 0$.
You can see this by expanding its Taylor series:
$$
e^{ax^2}
= 1 + ax^2 + \frac{ax^4}{2!} + \frac{ax^6}{3!} + \cdots
$$
Since all the coefficients are positive, $e^{ax^2}$ is bounded below by polynomials of arbitrarily high degree.
Thus, no polynomial $P$ bounds it above, because $P$ would also have to bound polynomials of arbitrarily high degree, which is impossible.

The may be able to come up with a bound using factorials, and/or functions like $p(x)^{q(x)}$ where $p(x)$ and $q(x)$ are polynomials.  You can also bound the function by a polynomial if you consider only a bounded domain.

Answer (score 1):

There is no upper bound of the type you mentioned.

$e^{ax^2}$ becomes very large compared to a polynomial.